# cannot separate the different parts of an ieee 754 floating point

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ieee-754

I am currently trying to separate the different parts of single precision floating point from IEEE 754 using C bitwise operators. I plan to put the separated parts in a struct. My end goal is to write arithmetic operations using bitwise operators.

I have however stumbled upon a little issue where my results don't make any sense whatsoever. I have been unable to find a solution to this problem and have been unable to find a solution on the internet. Any insight in this would be greatly appreciated.

The following is all the modules I've used.

```
    //test.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "splicing.h"
    
    int main(void)
    {
    
        float a = 5, b = -3, c = 0.1;
        sploat A, B, C;
    
        printf("%f\n%x\n", a, *(unsigned int*) &a);
        printf("%f\n%x\n", b, *(unsigned int*) &b);
        printf("%f\n%x\n\n", c, *(unsigned int*) &c);
    
        splice(a, A);
        splice(b, B);
        splice(c, C);
    
        printf("%f\n%hhu %hhi %x\n\n", a, A.s, A.e, A.m);
        printf("%f\n%hhu %hhi %x\n\n", b, B.s, B.e, B.m);
        printf("%f\n%hhu %hhi %x\n\n", c, C.s, C.e, C.m);
    
        return 0;
    
    }
    
    
    
    /*
     * Expected results
     *
     * 5 = 0x40a00000
     *  exp = +2
     *  man = 0x200000 (explicit) 0xa00000 (spliced)
     *  sign = 0
     *
     * -3 = 0xc0400000
     *      exp = +1
     *      man = 0x400000 (explicit) 0xc00000 (spliced)
     *      sign = 1
     *
     * 0.1 = 0x3dccccd
     *  exp = -4
     *  man = 0x4ccccc (explicit) 0xcccccc (spliced)
     *  sign = 0
     */
```

```
//splicing.h
typedef struct splicedflt{
    unsigned char s;        //sign
    signed char e;      //exponent
    unsigned int m;     //mantissa
} sploat;   //short for spliced float


//unfinished
//Makes inserted sploat reflect inserted float. The problem child I need help with.
int splice(float, sploat);

//splicing.c
int splice(float num, sploat strukt)
{

    unsigned int raw = *(unsigned int*) &num;   //floats don't allow for bitmagic.

    strukt.s = raw >> 31;
    strukt.e = (raw << 1) >> 24;
    strukt.m = ((raw << 9) >> 9) | 0x1000000;

    return 0;

}
```

The following is output from the program. I have no idea why this is not working.

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
5.000000
40a00000
-3.000000
c0400000
0.100000
3dcccccd

5.000000
0 0 0

-3.000000
160 0 5588

0.100000
160 -20 7ffe
$
```

Comment: Never use `*(unsigned int*) &a`. In C, use `(union { float f; unsigned u; }) {a} .u` or `FloatToRepresentation(a)` where `FloatToRepresentation` is defined with `static unsigned FloatToRepresentation(float x) { unsigned int u; memcpy(&u, &x, sizeof u); return u; }`. This presumes `float` and `unsigned` are the same size. (In C++, do not use the former.)

Comment: The preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number is “significand.” “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic (adding to a mantissa multiplies the number represented). Significands are linear (multiplying a significand multiplies the number represented).

Comment: Other problems include: `strukt.m = ((raw << 9) >> 9) | 0x1000000;` is an improper handling of 0,0 and sub-normals numbers.  Code does not account for infinities nor not-a-number.  The size of `float, unsigned` may differ.

Answer (score 1):

There are (as far as I can see) three issues in your code.

The first, very major issue is that you are passing your `spfloat` structures to the `splice` function **by value**; that is, a *copy* of the respective value is given to the function, and that copy is modified – the original structures (in your `main` function are thus left unchanged). To solve this, pass those structures 'by reference' (i.e., use pointers to the structures as the arguments).

With this fixed, your exponent fields will be wrong, because the IEEE-754 format uses [**biased exponents**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) – for single-precision (32-bit) floating point data, you can correct this (in most cases) by subtracting that bias (127) from the stored value.

You also have a potential issue with violation of [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/10871073) in your `unsigned int raw = *(unsigned int*) &num;` line; use the `memcpy` function to prevent this.

Here's a modified version of your `splice` function:

```c
int splice(float num, sploat* strukt) // Pass "strukt" as a pointer
{
    unsigned int raw;
    memcpy(&raw, &num, sizeof(raw)); // Avoid strict aliasing violation
    strukt->s = raw >> 31;
    strukt->e = (signed char)((raw << 1) >> 24) - 127; // Remove the BIAS
    strukt->m = ((raw << 9) >> 9) | 0x1000000;
    return 0;

}
```

And here's how that would be called in `main`:

```c
int main(void)
{
    float a = 5, b = -3, c = 0.1f;
    sploat A, B, C;

    //...

    splice(a, &A); // Pass the ADDRESS of each structure...
    splice(b, &B);
    splice(c, &C);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A call of the form `splice(a, A);` cannot change `A` because the call only passes the value of `A` to the function. Neither the address nor any other way of accessing `A` is passed to the function.

Change `splice` so that it takes a `float` argument and returns a `sploat` value:

```
sploat splice(float num)
{
    sploat S;

    unsigned raw = (union { float f; unsigned u; }) {num} .u;

    S.s = raw >> 31;
    S.e = (raw << 1) >> 24;
    S.m = ((raw << 9) >> 9) | 0x1000000;

    return S;
}
```

Change the calls to match:

```
    A = splice(a);
    B = splice(b);
    C = splice(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference to your struct. At the moment your function is not modifying the `strukt` parameter as it is passed by **value** and you change the **local** copy of it.

You also have to avoid pointer punning as it breaks strict aliasing rules. Use `memcpy` instead.

```
int splice(float num, sploat *strukt)
{

    unsigned raw;
    memcpy(&raw, &num, sizeof(raw));

    strukt -> s = raw >> 31;
    strukt -> e = (raw << 1) >> 24;
    strukt -> m = ((raw << 9) >> 9) | 0x1000000;
    return 0;
}
```

```
    splice(a, &A);
    splice(b, &B);
    splice(c, &C);
```

PS I did not modify your bitshift logic as it is your homework not mine.

Comment: You forgot about the exponent bias.

Comment: @AdrianMole I actually did not check the bitwise logic :) Some work has to be done by OP